# What happens when I allocate memory space for line buffering and the lines of the stream have more bytes than the buffer space?

Tags: c

This code allocates just 10 bytes for line buffering and reads a file which have a 45 bytes first line.
When it runs, the program reads all the 45 bytes not just the first 10 bytes as I expected it to do, so what **setvbuf** actually did?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *tst;
    tst = fopen("x.log","r");

    char *buff = malloc(10); //Just 10 characters
    setvbuf(tst, buff, _IOLBF, 10);

    char *mystring = malloc(45); //First line of x.log is 45 characters exactly
    if ( fgets (mystring, 45, tst) != NULL )
        puts(mystring);
    fclose (tst);
    free(buff);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets()` uses `getc()` internally, to read one character at a time, until it reads a newline or reaches the limit it was given. Whenever `getc()` reaches the end of the I/O buffer, it will refill the buffer, so it's not limited to the size set by `setvbuf()`. Setting a small buffer size just makes it less efficient, but doesn't change the amount of data that can be read.

Comment: So, it has just **cleared** the 10 bytes buffer four times to read the 45 bytes line?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.

Answer (score 1):

setvbuf associates with the file a buffer of size 10.

Why reads all 45 bytes?

You are reading the file with fgets, and trying to read 45 bytes. Since the file buffer is size 10 (and _IOLBF option), this means the read is done this way:

1. Read bytes 0-9 from file to mystring
2. Read bytes 10-19...
3. Read bytes 20-29...
4. Read bytes 30-39...
5. Read bytes 40-45 and stops at \n

Instead of use a default buffer and probably reading all bytes at once (without refilling the buffer)

Answer (score 1):

```
setvbuf(tst, buff, _IOLBF, csize * 10);
```

You set buffering mode to _IOLBF = Line Buffered, according to the
man page of setvbuf "...when  it  is  line  buffered characters are saved up until a newline..."

```
setvbuf(tst, buff, _IOFBF, csize * 10);
```

Should buffer only 10 Bytes, but fgets would still read the full line.

Buffering means, internal the Data is read to buff, when buff is full or in line buffered also when a Newline is read, the buffer is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The difference without and with `setvbuf` is,

```
open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)              = 3
read(3, "Hickanckdnckncksckscskcnnacnckad"..., 4096) = 65

Vs

open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)              = 3
read(3, "Hickanckdn", 10)               = 10
read(3, "cknckscksc", 10)               = 10
read(3, "skcnnacnck", 10)               = 10
read(3, "adjsnccnad", 10)               = 10 
read(3, "ncacsjcadj", 10)               = 10
```

`fgets()` reads in `4096` chucks of bytes at a time. `setvbuf` is the way to control and how large is the buffer while `read`.